# Running Craft on a subpath

Tags: url, config, craft4, routing

We are trying to run Craft CMS not under `example.com` but under `example.com/subpath`.
So we want the following paths:

- Frontend: `example.com/subpath`
- controlPanel: `example.com/subpath/admin`

In the `.env`

```
PIRMARY_SITE_URL=example.com/subpath
```

Which is also used inside the Settings for the base url.

In the `general.php`

```
->aliases([
        '@web' => App::env('PRIMARY_SITE_URL'),
        '@webroot' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/web',
    ])
    ->baseCpUrl(App::env('PRIMARY_SITE_URL'))
```

Everything "works". Except axios requests.
For example: trying to login to the controlpanel results into an 404. Because it tries to call `http://example.com/index.php?p=admin%2Factions%2Fusers%2Flogin&v=1709708188780`

> deleting the cpressourcen does nothing. axios somewhere gets the wrong base url.

I think im missing a setting. I don not thing their is a problem with the webserver?

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Das Problem lag an der Craft CMS Version < `4.8.1` / `4.8.2`.

Konnte mit `4.8.3` geloest werden.